# Best way to record changes to a SQL Server Database and send them to the client?

Tags: php, sql-server, ajax, sql-server-2008

I have a simple SQL Server database with 12 tables.  Each table has 100 to 1000 rows.  These tables are saved directly into arrays when my web app loads.  From that point on, the arrays are used rather than direct table access.  The arrays need to be updated whenever another user changes the data in the database.

To do this, I'm planning on using ajax to poll a PHP script every 10 seconds.  This script checks for changes on any of these 12 tables and returns to the client machine only the changes that have been made rather than the whole table.

The problem is, I don't know how to record any changes to these 12 tables and then return those changes to the client machine in a way that they can be interpreted in Javascript to update arrays.

What is the best/easiest way to keep track of changes to tables in SQL Server?

---

Perhaps a clearer way to ask my question that is more widely applicable - what methods are there to query or discover changes to SQL Server tables over time?

Comment: Read through cache. Invalidate the cache when the data changes.

Comment: There are many, many ways to do this and none of them will be necessarily simple enough for us to want to write for you. Is there a reason you don't want to just query the table?

Comment: How in the WORLD is this too localized? Because I provided TOO MUCH information about my specific case? How is wanting to create parity between local data and server-side data not something dealt with by programmers across the world every single day? I was just looking for some suggestions on approaches to do this with SQL Server - not entire write ups doing it for me.  Something like the suggestions I got - read through the cache, keep a last update table or field, and change data capture - which is exactly what I was looking for and many others might need!

Comment: I don't want to just query the table because pulling 12 complete tables over ajax every 10 seconds is enough to bring a lot of people's internet connections to a halt.  Thus I just want to query the changes to a table.

Comment: One more thought. I'm sorry if I sound upset - I really appreciate the stackoverflow community. I'm just having a hard time understanding. There was enough demand for an answer to my specific question that Microsoft added Change Data Capture in SQL Server 2008 - something specifically designed just for this use case!  Obviously it is not a localized need! So what's the correct path for me now?  Do I create a new question and try to word it more generally, edit this one to make it more general, or just give up?

Comment: "Too localized"? Seriously? That doesn't even make sense. "Not constructive" for being too open-ended *maybe*, or off-topic if it seems too DB-oriented, but too localized is ridiculous.

Comment: @C.A. McCann Thanks!  I know!  I could possibly see too open-ended (I did use the dreaded "best/easiest" words by accident), but too localized?  This is a quote straight from an MSDN article on the issue: "Many applications require that changes be tracked in the server database so that these changes can be delivered to clients during a subsequent synchronization session."  That's EXACTLY what this question is about!  Thanks to those who pointed me in the right directions!

Comment: I agree with your earlier comment dallin.  If it was "localized" then why would Microsoft have built not one but 2 specific tools into SQL Server 2008 to handle exactly what you were looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might also look into change data capture.  It sounds like exactly what you need.  Here is BOL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489%28v=sql.105%29.aspx.
And here is an article on it by Pinal Dave: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/15/sql-server-introduction-to-change-data-capture-cdc-in-sql-server-2008/

Basically it records all changes (inserts, updates and deletes) and allows you to pull the information from system tables.  Unfortunately I don't know enough about it myself other than to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks Kenneth!  This is EXACTLY what I was looking for!  After investigating CDC, I actually found out SQL Server 2008 has two solutions for this - Change Data Capture and Change Tracking.  Change Tracking does the same thing but is more light weight, is included in SQL Server Express, but lacks a historical record of the data before it was changed.  Both solutions are new in SQL Server 2008, and a custom solution is required before that.  I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 1):

I believe I misread your question at first glance, but it appears you're storing the data in a javascript array. If so, keep a "last updated" time stamp in javascript and maintain a "last updated" column in your database. As one of the comments said, it's a bit much to actually code here, but one idea:

initial.php - load the page with all data held in memory within a javascript variable, this page will poll checkforupdates.php?lastUpdate=[the most recently updated timestamp]

checkforupdates.php - run an SQL query with "WHERE lastUpdate > providedTimestamp", echo json_encode($data)

Is this enough to point you in the right direction?

Comment: You have to factor for deletions, if the app allows for deletions.

Comment: Thanks thatthatisis!  This is along the lines of what I was thinking.  I may go with this approach if I need to support SQL Server 2005.  Otherwise, Kenneth's answer led me to Change Tracking, an integrated feature in SQL Server 2008 that solves this problem.